# jQuery Hover for a Single Item of a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a group of divs that are being populated dynamically that highlight photos and names of individuals, about a hundred in all:

HTML:

```
<div class="profile-pic-wrap">
     <div class="profile-pic">
          <div class="profile-btn-bg">
               <a href="#linktoBio">
                    <img class="instructor" src="bioPic.jpg" border="0">
               </a>
          </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#linktoBio" class="instructor-name">Name of Guy</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile-btn-bg a, a.instructor-name{
     background: none;
}

.profile-btn-bg a.hovered, a.instructor-name.hovered, .profile-btn-bg a:hover, a.instructor-name:hover{
     background: #ff0000;
}
```

I'm looking to write a bit og jQuery that when you hover over the LINK holding the IMAGE, that the style of that link AND the link holding the NAME both change, and vice-versa.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".profile-btn-bg a").hover(function(){
        $("a.instructor-name").toggleClass("hovered");
    });

    $("a.instructor-name").hover(function(){
        $(".profile-btn-bg a").toggleClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

but that changes ALL of them, and not just the group I am hovering over.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to limit the search inside the closest `.profile-pic-wrap` element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".profile-btn-bg a").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest('.profile-pic-wrap').find("a.instructor-name").toggleClass("hovered");
    });

    $("a.instructor-name").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest('.profile-pic-wrap').find(".profile-btn-bg a").toggleClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the default parameter passed to your hover callbacks (`Event eventObject`), for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".profile-btn-bg a").hover(function(event){
      event.target.toggleClass("hovered");
  });

  $("a.instructor-name").hover(function(event){
      event.target.toggleClass("hovered");
  });
});
```